# Google.Apis.Auth error. cant authenticate my project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms

GoogleCredential is missing,
ServiceAccountCredential is missing,
googlewebauthorizationbroker is missing
from the new "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/" 
.
.
I am using Xamarin MonoAndroid V6.
.

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
 using Google.Apis.Auth;
 using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
 using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
 using Google.Apis.Services;
 using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FBLogin
{


    public class GmailLogin
        {

        static string[] Scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" };
       }
  }
```

Comment: //this guy is awesome. He just solved the issue in a simple way.. check this out guys.. "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Google/"

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Your link in your comment seems to be broken by my side.

Comment: //No worries @buddy. Even that didn't work. :( it implements web app authentication(using HttpClient) which is not supported by google api for installed apps. try searching in nuget with a keyword "plugin.Google" you will find the nuget.

Comment: //For Facebook, you can use this API guys. even I have to test."https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Facebook/". Its a platform specific API